# Mongo DB Search Query

Tags: mongodb, find

I have Written the Following code in my program but it is treating every word as seprate keyword.... I want full sentence to be treated as one keyword only.

```
var typed =typing.substring(4,typing.indexOf(":")-3)
db.collection('Question').find({$text:{$search : typed }},{projection:{_id: 0, Question:1}}).toArray(function(err, result) 
    {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    })
```

$text is index name on my database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply quote your string like this to make MongoDB search for the literal text:

```
var typed = '\"' + typing.substring(4,typing.indexOf(":")-3) + '\"'
```

Also see the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#search-field) on this.